# Trouble Parsing XML using Go

Tags: xml, go

I've been trying to parse an xml in Go by defining structs and using xml.Unmarshal like this:

```
type InitiateResponse struct {
    SoapenvEnvelope struct {
        SoapenvBody struct {
            ReqResponseMsg struct {
                CData struct {
                    Response struct {
                        ResponseCode string `xml:"ResponseCode"`
                        ConversationID string `xml:"ConversationID"`
                        ResponseDesc string `xml:"ResponseDesc"`
                        OriginatorConversationID string `xml:"OriginatorConversationID"`
                        ServiceStatus string `xml:"ServiceStatus"`
                    } `xml:"req:Response"`
                } `xml: ![CDATA[`
            } `xml:"req:ResponseMsg"`
        } `xml:"soapenv:Body"`
    } `xml:"soapenv:Envelope"`
}   

var unit InitiateResponse
if err := xml.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &unit); err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    return
}
```

There's no error thrown but the struct is always empty at the end. Can't understand why.

This is the xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:req="http://cps.huawei.com/cpsinterface/request">
   <soapenv:Header />
   <soapenv:Body>
      <req:ResponseMsg><![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Response><ResponseCode>14</ResponseCode><ConversationID>AG_20170222_000040cdc5cecf730e39</ConversationID><ResponseDesc>The caller information is invalid.</ResponseDesc><OriginatorConversationID>S_X2013012921001</OriginatorConversationID><ServiceStatus>2</ServiceStatus></Response>]]></req:ResponseMsg>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Check it out:
https://play.golang.org/p/Irmy8AsUKa

Comment: Your code is missing a `print(err)` at the end, which will tell you more about the error.

Comment: didn't include it here but there's no err. It parses successfully but the struct remains empty.

Comment: Adding  go play ground would be great

Comment: @SarathSadasivanPillai done

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CDATA can not be unmarshalled to a struct.

> - If the XML element contains character data, that data is accumulated in the first struct field that has tag ",chardata".    The
>     struct field may have type []byte or string.    If there is no such
>     field, the character data is discarded.

An attempt to unmarshal CDATA to struct will fail with following error

```
cannot unmarshal into struct
```

This playground [link](https://play.golang.org/p/i9RPl3QB50) explains the above mentioned problem.

There were some other issues with the struct.Go currently does not support `XML namespace prefixes` .Here is an open issue regarding the same https://github.com/golang/go/issues/9519.

Here is code re-written

**Code**

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
)

const data = `<soapenv:Envelope>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <req:ResponseMsg>
        <name>blah</name>
            <![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Response><ResponseCode>14</ResponseCode><ConversationID>AG_20170222_00006f8794f700eff099</ConversationID><ResponseDesc>The caller information is invalid.</ResponseDesc><OriginatorConversationID>S_X2013012921001</OriginatorConversationID><ServiceStatus>2</ServiceStatus></Response>]]>
        </req:ResponseMsg>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>`

type Envelop struct {
    XMLName     xml.Name `xml:"Envelope"`
    ResponseMsg struct {
        CDATA []byte `xml:",cdata"`
    } `xml:"Body>ResponseMsg"`
}

type Response struct {
    XMLName                  xml.Name `xml:"Response"`
    ResponseCode             string   `xml:"ResponseCode"`
    ConversationID           string   `xml:"ConversationID"`
    ResponseDesc             string   `xml:"ResponseDesc"`
    OriginatorConversationID string   `xml:"OriginatorConversationID"`
    ServiceStatus            string   `xml:"ServiceStatus"`
}

func main() {
    var unit Envelop
    if err := xml.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &unit); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    responseBytes := unit.ResponseMsg.CDATA
    var response Response
    if err := xml.Unmarshal([]byte(responseBytes), &response); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println("Response : ", response)

}
```

Here is the play link : [play.golang](https://play.golang.org/p/sCREQKN3BV)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I had given up and had to resort to converting the xml to json to make it work. :D
Really appreciate it.

Comment: @JarriAbidi happy to help